# Why is Series with Abs giving an imaginary unit as output?

Tags: functions, complex, series-expansion

I have a simple integral of an absolute value. However, the output is showing an imaginary unit. In a previous question I have been told the problem is the `Series`. Can anybody help?

Adding `ComplexExpand` doesn't seem to help. I really believe I shouldn't see any `I`, can anybody confirm that? I am having a lot of problems to understand why `I` appears.

```
 dWNorm[x_] = 
Piecewise[{{(-c *(B1  Cos[B1 x] - B1  Cosh[B1  x]) - B1  Sin[B1  x] -
   B1  Sinh[B1  x]), 0 <= x <= 1}}]
IntegrandON[x_, z_] = 
Abs[Series[(1 - ((1 - I)/2)*Sqrt[beta/2]*
     Cosh[(1 - I)*z*
        Sqrt[beta/2]]/(Sinh[(1 - I)/2*Sqrt[ beta/2]]))*(dWNorm[
    x]), {beta, 0, 2}]]^2;
IntegralON = 
beta/(16*Integrate[IntegrandON[x, z], {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1/2, 1/2}])
```

Comment: What is dWNorm?

Comment: @user64494 it is my own defined function. I can edit it but I don't see why that is important for what I asked. B1 is a real, c too.

Comment: That imaginary unit is showing up inside the `Abs`, just like it does here: `In[224]:= Abs[1 + I*x]

Out[224]= Abs[1 + I x]`. I see no issue with that.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau But as I stated, using ComplexExpand didnt help. If you do `Abs[1+I*x]//ComplexExpand` you get in fact `Sqrt[1+x^2]`

Comment: Might try it with `ComplexExpand[Abs[Normal[Series[...]]]`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dWNorm[x_] = 
  Piecewise[{{(-c*(B1 Cos[B1 x] - B1 Cosh[B1 x]) - B1 Sin[B1 x] - 
       B1 Sinh[B1 x]), 0 <= x <= 1}}];
```

Use [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) after the [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html). Use [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html) to simplify the combination of [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) functions. Since you mentioned [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) without stating any limitations, I assume that all variables are real. Use `TargetFunctions->{Re, Im}` with `ComplexExpand`

```
IntegrandON[x_, z_] = Abs[
       Series[(1 - ((1 - I)/2)*Sqrt[beta/2]*
             Cosh[(1 - I)*z*
                Sqrt[beta/2]]/(Sinh[(1 - I)/2*Sqrt[beta/2]]))*(dWNorm[
            x]), {beta, 0, 2}] // Normal]^2 //
     PiecewiseExpand //
    ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & //
   Simplify;

IntegralON = 
 beta/(16*Integrate[IntegrandON[x, z], {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1/2, 1/2}]) // 
  FullSimplify

(*  302400/(B1 beta (1680 + beta^2) (2 c (-2 + 2 B1 c - Cos[2 B1]) - 
     2 c Cosh[2 B1] + 
     4 Cosh[B1] (2 c Cos[B1] + Sin[B1] - c^2 Sin[B1]) + (-1 + c^2) Sin[
       2 B1] - 4 (1 + c^2) Cos[B1] Sinh[B1] + Sinh[2 B1] + c^2 Sinh[2 B1]))  *)
```

Comment: I thank you for your answer. I will now try to understand: in the meantime could you mention WHY I have to do all this? Why isn't it automatically giving the result without any `I`? My big doubt is: if I hadn't done all the things you showed, would the result have been wrong? Or would it have been given in another output form, but still correct? What I am doubtful of is: if I dont give all these extra information after Abs, are the two results Completely different?

Comment: Read the doc for `Series` and `Normal`  for why `Normal` is needed. Read docs for `PiecewiseExpand` to see why it is used. `Abs` is a perfectly reasonable and compact way of expressing a real value. `ComplexExpand` doesn't know that you want another representation and has no reason to change the expression unless you specify that you want different `TargetFunctions`.

Comment: Ok, I will do all you said: can you discuss about my doubt on the correctness of both the outputs?That is: is my code wrong or just different from yours in terms of output form? This is really important for me to understand better Mathematica

Comment: @AndreaG - there are multiple equivalent representations for any expression; the specific one used is dependent on the context. Mma in general operates in the complex plane and "complex looking" representations of real expressions arise from the algorithms that are built to handle complex expressions. As stated previously, `ComplexExpand` is correct in considering `Abs[expr]` as real and if you want a different representation you need to specify other `TargetFunctions`.

Comment: @AndreaG - For an example of real-valued expressions that **must** contain complex-valued expressions, see [`Casus irreducibilis`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis)